# How can I find out the vfstype of a hard drive partition?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount, busybox

How do I find out the vfstype of a hard drive partition when it is unmounted in BusyBox?

My question is specific for BusyBox since I am trying to do a mount during a Debian install.

If I do `fdisk -l` I get a label that just says "Linux". This does tell me if the partition is ext2 or ext3 or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- With a modern version of `mount` the file-system type should not need to be specified.
- `sudo blkid` displays **label**, **uuid** and **type** (and `lsblk` to display **capacities**)
- `file -s /dev/sdX#` does the job for *partitions* as well as *disk images*.
- `ls /sys/block/*/*` is a good resource for many things (but not determining filesystem type)

I assume this is an embedded device, otherwise you should be taking advantage of **coreutils**, **util-linux**, etc. rather than **busybox**.

Let me make this clear, *busybox* is not consistent across the board - various vendors strip out commands or cripple them to varied degrees. That said, **blkid** *should* be available. Run `busybox --help` which will list the commands compiled into the busybox binary. Also note that often not all those symlinks will exist, so you may need to create them as needed.